# I got the text from a dropdown and stored in a string and Im trying to locate an element with the text I got

Tags: java, selenium, testng

The xpath to locate element is

`//div[@class='modal-body']//div//span[starts-with(text(),'Bar/lounge')]`

`Bar/lounge` is the text I got from a dropdown, I will just call the string I stored in that texts place.The problem is now I want bar alone .same case for the below texts these are the inputs I got through data provider from the dropdown.Is
there way to satisfy in the xpath itself .
[The texts are :

```
Conference space,
Swimming pool,
Free airport transportation,
Free WiFi,
Breakfast service,
Business services,
Bar/lounge,
Restaurant,
Fitness facilities]
```

Comment: You've `Bar/lounge` in your data provider so why do you want `Bar` alone? Also for other text I do not see what exactly you are asking for.

Comment: Because the text availabe in another place is Bar (which I want to validate with the text I got from dataprovider).Im passing all the texts mentioned above one by one in the place of bar/lounge (xpath)

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the elements that contain a certain text. Then, select the one you need and click it:

```
List<WebElement> myElements = driver.findElementsByXpath("//*[contains(text(),'Bar')]") 
// this maybe another index, here is just an example
WebElement barElm = myElements[1];
barElm.click();
```